# What does the last parameter of glVertexAttribPointer mean?

Tags: opengl, parameters

I began learning OpenGL, but I don't understand what the last parameter in `glVertexAttribPointer` means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a pointer offset into the array you're using. However, it's a byte count that you have to cast to a pointer, which isn't exactly intuitive.

If you're using interleaved attributes, it's the number of bytes from the beginning to the first instance of that attribute.

Example:

```
VVVNNNTTVVVNNTT
```

Where Vertex position data, N is the normal vector, and T is the texture corodinate.

The offset for V is `0` (it's at the beginning)

The offset for N is `(GLvoid*) (3*sizeof(vertex data type))`

The offset for T is `(GLvoid*) (3*sizeof(vertex data type) + 3*sizeof(normal data type) )`

Furthermore, if you have successive attributes, it would be the starting point for each attribute as well.

Example:

```
VVVV...VVVNNN...NNNTT...TT
```

The offset for V is `0` (it's at the beginning)

The offset for N is `(GLvoid*) (3*sizeof(vertex data type)*number_of_vertices)`

The offset for T is `(GLvoid*) (3*sizeof(vertex data type)*number_of_vertices + 3*sizeof(normal data type)*number_of_normals)`